# How i will find the same value in my row and put it in CASE

Tags: mysql

hi can you help me guys in my sql CASE statement or how i will manipulate the data. i was trying to find the same value of my row value .. and if they are same give a temporary column with a value of 1 with a same name in my database. 
ex. this is my table

```
  id     company
------|-----------
   1  |  Inzpect
   2  |  Meralco
   3  |  Ginebra
   4  |  Inzpect
```

my sql is

```
SELECT company, (CASE WHEN company = 'Inzpect' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS external_customer FROM tbl_reports
```

the result is

```
 company   external
---------|-----------
Inzpect  |     1
Meralco  |     0
Ginebra  |     0
Inzpect  |     1
```

but how can i manipulate the data that i will no longer using the 'Inzpect' string in CASE and change it to another statement that will find same value of row automatically without manually putting a value.

```
CASE WHEN company = 'Inzpect'
```

Comment: You had me up until `but how can i manipulate the data` ... what are you asking here?

Comment: i am tryng to change that it will automatically find the same value and not using a string data with a same value in here "WHEN company = 'Inzpect' "

Comment: You lost me at 'hi'.

Comment: What was the desired result again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
SELECT
    t1.company,
    CASE WHEN t2.company IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS external
FROM tbl_reports t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT company
    FROM tbl_reports
    GROUP BY company
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.company = t2.company
```

Comment: sr is it possible if all row with the same value per month will group as 1 row.. 
example if there is 
two same row value in just one month it will group it by 1 row but per month only not all row with a same value will be group by 1..

Comment: @ElliJoshuaRey Update your question and show table data containing date/month information.  Better yet, ask a new question.